# UIAlertView crashes in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, ios7

We had compiled and deployed an app in iOS 6 environment.  But, now the app is getting crash in iOS 7 whenever showing an alert.
App simply getting crash in *[alertView show];*

But, the same app is running perfect in iOS 6.

Code for showing alert

```
-(void)displayAlertWithMessage:(NSString *)message withTitle:(NSString *)title andTag:(int)tag
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

and calling like this

```
[self displayAlertWithMessage:@"Please enter valid username!" withTitle:nil andTag:1];
```

Here, is the crash log.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/developer/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/A0BCB945-8E4A-4D06-BEE8-240FF45ECF78/MyProject.app> (loaded)' with name '_UIModalItemAppViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x003176f4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x027c88b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x003174cb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   UIKit                               0x015d1bec -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 951
    4   UIKit                               0x01444f05 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
    5   UIKit                               0x014456ad -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
    6   UIKit                               0x014459ae -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    7   UIKit                               0x01445eb4 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    8   UIKit                               0x018dc9da -[_UIModalItemsCoordinator _presentingViewControllerForAlertCompatibilityCreateIfNeeded:] + 248
    9   UIKit                               0x018dc8dd -[_UIModalItemsCoordinator _presentingViewControllerForAlertCompatibility] + 41
    10  UIKit                               0x01812801 -[UIAlertView(Private) popupAlertAnimated:animationType:atOffset:] + 382
    11  UIKit                               0x01812c1d -[UIAlertView(Private) popupAlertAnimated:animationType:] + 56
    12  UIKit                               0x01817c17 -[UIAlertView showWithAnimationType:] + 48
    13  UIKit                               0x01817c45 -[UIAlertView show] + 41
    14  MyProject                        0x000330a8 -[LoginViewController displayAlertWithMessage:withTitle:andTag:] + 232
    15  MyProject                        0x00032e8b -[LoginViewController isValidContent] + 299
    16  MyProject                        0x00033136 -[LoginViewController showSetPinView] + 54
    17  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x027da874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    18  UIKit                               0x0133524c -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    19  UIKit                               0x013351d8 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    20  UIKit                               0x0142ba5d -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    21  UIKit                               0x0142be20 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    22  UIKit                               0x0142b0cf -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    23  UIKit                               0x0137221d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    24  UIKit                               0x01372e84 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
    25  UIKit                               0x01346b86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    26  MyProject                        0x000c2c75 -[Application sendEvent:] + 101
    27  UIKit                               0x0133135f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x002a096f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x002a02fb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x002bd3ce __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x002bcbf3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x002bca0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    33  GraphicsServices                    0x036f0a27 GSEventRunModal + 192
    34  GraphicsServices                    0x036f084e GSEventRun + 104
    35  UIKit                               0x01333f0b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    36  MyProject                        0x00006612 main + 178
    37  MyProject                        0x00006555 start + 53
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your code? Have you looked at the difference in how it's implemented in iOS7?

Comment: Updated the question with sample code please check..

Comment: Is your Xcode / iOS 7 install complete? The exception says it couldn't load a NIB.

Comment: @Wain, this app is developed in xcode 4.5 and went to app store also.  But, now the same build is getting crash because of this reason.  At present for debugging this issue I am using xcode 5 beta version and ios 7 beta version.

Comment: Update to latest Xcode, don't use a beta which might have bugs.

Comment: @Wain, Now my issue is the build which is in app store also getting crash due to this reason in ios7 only.

Comment: might be some oriantation isse It's because the Alert is trying to display in an orientation different from the current view. take a look [UIAlertView crashes the app at runtime](https://devforums.apple.com/message/887255#887255)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per crash log it says to me **"[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:]"** unable to load nib file.

But, in my project I had created a category for *UIViewController* class and overridden the `-(id)init` method.  Upto ios6, while showing an alert this category method is not at all executing, but from ios7 onwards overridden *init()* method of *UIViewController*.

So, I fixed this issue by adding the another *validation in UIViewController category's init() method for checking the class method is UIAlertView or not*, if it is UIAlertView then simply calling `[super init];`  instead of doing my other stuff relating to view controllers.

Sample code:

```
    - (id)init
    {
          NSString *viewControllerName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self class]];
          if([viewControllerName isEqualToString:@"UIAlertView"])
          {
             self = [super init];
          }
          else
          {
             // my stuff
          }
          return self;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can test it.. try to avoid nil.. instead of that put something...  like
[self displayAlertWithMessage:@"Please enter valid username!" withTitle:@"Hello" andTag:1]

and you need to release alert view so in function write release code...